# Alert on SMART failures?

Tags: centos, hard-disk

I have `smartctl` on my Linux server and I want to automate alerts if any SMART failures start to appear or if the health degrades.

Obviously I can schedule a cron to do something like:

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sda
```

But how can I monitor the results of this of health failures? I know how to set up email alerts, I am just not sure the best way to trigger off SMART health issues.

Comment: cronjob for -t short? why not use smartd... which does these, and the email alerts, and custom warning scripts if you need them ...?